# Convert promises to async/await with Firebase queries

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, promise

I have some firebase queries where I am using their recommended promises but I am running to a problem. I need the code to go through the steps in order but the last snippet of code is running before the prior code finishes. I would like to use async/await but I am not sure exactly how to do it.

here is my current code:

```
if (result.user.emailVerified) {
  let ref = db.collection('users').where('email', '==', result.user.email)
  ref.get().then(snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.empty) {
      let cid = null
      let docID = null
      let groupID = null

      let pendingRef = db.collection('pendingusers')
      pendingRef = pendingRef.where('email', '==', result.user.email)
      pendingRef.get().then(snapshot => {

        if (!snapshot.empty) {
          snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            cid = doc.data().cid
            docID = doc.id
            groupID = doc.data().groupID
          })
        }

      }).then(() => {
        db.collection('users').add({
          url: null,
          fullPath: null,
          roles: ['member'],
          uid: result.user.uid,
          email: result.user.email,
          emailVerified: result.user.emailVerified,
          cid: cid,
          active: null,
          joined: Date.now()
        }).then(() => {

          // STEP 1
          console.log('1. user has been added')

          if (groupID !== null) {
            db.collection('groups').doc(groupID).update({
              members: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(result.user.uid)
            }).then(() => {

              // STEP 2
              console.log('2. group has been updated')
            })
          }

        }).then(() => {
          if (docID !== null) {
            db.collection('pendingusers').doc(docID).delete()
              .then(() => {

                // STEP 3
                console.log('3. removed from pending ', cid)

                let churchRef = db.collection('churches')
                churchRef = churchRef.where('cid', '==', cid)
                churchRef.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
                  if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
                    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {

                      // STEP 4
                      console.log('4. data ', doc.data())

                      dispatch('AppData/resetNotifications', [], {
                        root: true
                      })
                      dispatch('AppData/resetUnits', [], {
                        root: true
                      })
                      dispatch('AppData/isRunning', false, {
                        root: true
                      })

                      dispatch('AppData/setChurchId', doc.data().cid, {
                        root: true
                      })
                      // set the church
                      dispatch('AppData/allChurches', [{
                        churchtitle: doc.data().churchtitle,
                        cid: doc.data().cid,
                      }], {
                        root: true
                      })
                    })
                  }
                })

              })
          }
        })
      })
    } else {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        commit('updateUser', {
          cid: doc.data().cid,
          url: doc.data().url,
          fullPath: doc.data().fullPath,
          user_name: doc.data().user_name
        })

        dispatch('AppData/getCourse', {
          cid: doc.data().cid,
          userid: doc.data()
        }, {
          root: true
        })
        dispatch('AppData/getActiveCourse', {
          cid: doc.data().cid,
          user: doc.data()
        }, {
          root: true
        })
      })
    }
  }).then(() => {

    // STEP 5
    console.log('5. next step')

    dispatch('AppData/getSections', {}, {
      root: true
    })
    dispatch('AppData/getUnits', {}, {
      root: true
    })
    dispatch('AppData/getMissions', {}, {
      root: true
    })
    dispatch('AppData/getWeeks', {}, {
      root: true
    })

    // get user's current roles
    let ref = db.collection('users').where('email', '==', result.user.email)
    ref.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
        let docs = change.doc
        commit('setRoles', docs.data().roles)
      })
    })

    router.push('home')
  })

} else {
  // console.log('not verified')
  commit('setLoginFeedback', {
    code: 'no-verfied email',
    message: 'You must first verifiy your email.'
  });
}
```

I have commented the steps to help illustrate the flow. I would like the code to go from step 1,2,3,4,5 but currently it goes 5,1,2,3,4

I know async/await will solve this, I just need some guidance on converting the code from then() to async/await

Comment: `async`/`await` still uses promises. The only thing you can replace with the syntactic sugar is `.then()` calls.